# XML As XMLNode in Actionscript/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

How do I get the root node of an XML object in Actionscript?

One would think that I could say this:

```
var Node:XMLNode = XMLVar as XMLNode;
```

But although XMLVar is of type XML, Node will = null.

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var node:XMLNode = xmlVar as XMLNode;
```

> although xmlVar is of type `XML`

[`XML`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html) and [`XMLNode`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/xml/XMLNode.html) are not compatible in ActionScript-3. `XML` class of AS2 (and its related classes) has been renamed to `flash.xml.XMLDocument` in AS3.

> The `XMLNode`/`XMLDocument` class represents the legacy `XML` object that was present in ActionScript 2.0 and that was renamed in ActionScript 3.0. In ActionScript 3.0, consider using the new top-level `XML` class and related classes instead, which support E4X (ECMAScript for XML). The `XMLNode`/`XMLDocument` class is present for backward compatibility.

An object of type `XML` cannot be cast directly to `XMLNode`. Since you're trying to cast with `as` keyword, it just returns `null` instead of raising an alarm saying the cast failed.

---

And as already mentioned, consider using lowerCase names for variables, as UpperCase names are normally used for naming classes.

Comment: Little mixup in above response, XML is AS3 while XMLDocument is AS2. Otherwise this answer is absolutely correct. (For the benefit of the original poster)

Comment: @Tyler AS2 had a top level `XML` class; it has been retained as `flash.xml.XMLDocument` in AS3 for backward compatibility. The top level `XMLNode` class in AS2 has been moved to `flash.xml.XMLNode`. AS3 has a top level `XML` class that supports e4x. Search for "XML class" in this AS2 to AS3 migration reference http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/migration.html

Answer (score 2):

You code is a little confusing because you are using uppercase first characters for you variable names. Take a look at [Adobe's coding conventions for AS3](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions#CodingConventions-Property%28variableandgetter%2Fsetter%29names).

```
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var node:XMLNode = xmlData.firstChild();
```

This example is pretty useless, but it just demonstrate the method.

Use the [XML object's firstChild method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/labs/flashauthoringpreview/flash/xml/XMLNode.html#firstChild). To get the first node as a XMLNode object.